# TypeScript: Symbol 'Date' cannot be properly resolved

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am quite new to TypeScript however I have some experience of C#. I am trying to declare the Date type variable in TypeScript but getting an error:

> Symbol 'Date' cannot be properly resolved

I have also tried to throw an `alert()` and then it says:

> Symbol 'alert' cannot be properly resolved

Can anyone please advise me what I am missing here, I am writing this Application is Visual Studio 2017.

```
const date: Date = new Date();
let today = date.yyyymmdd();
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: try to compile it , does it give the same error then?

Comment: it compiles. However when I tried the file in VS Code, looks like it is working there!

Comment: yeah. i think it might be an IDE issue